# combine template inside Component's template with codes inside html pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is a portion of my code inside home.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: `
<ion-header><ion-navbar><ion-title>SheetJS Ionic Demo</ion-title></ion-navbar></ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
`
})
```

As per my understanding, the code above will 'override' all codes inside home.html. Means for example although my home.html has the code below inside,

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

when the time to render the page comes, only the portion written under template inside home.ts will be displayed.

So my question is, is there any way I can combine the codes written under template inside home.ts with codes inside home.html?

Means something like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: `
<ion-header><ion-navbar><ion-title>SheetJS Ionic Demo</ion-title></ion-navbar></ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
   $ContentFromHtmlPage
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
`
})
```

so $ContentFromHtmlPage will be replaced with the codes inside home.html.

Personally I just hate seeing many codes written inside template: `` because I think it jumbles up the view and other section of the code.

Is this even possible with angular & ionic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do it directly, Angular does not allow combining the `templateUrl` and `template` properties inside a `@Component` decorator. And anyway this does not seem anyway logical and is struggling against the framework.

But the framework itself actually gives a solution (which is the exact thing why we use Angular in the first place).

Create another component and place the html template you need inside `home.ts` there.

This way you

- Will solve your issue
- Have a reusable component - what if you need the same template somewhere else?
- Separation of concerns

Referring to your comment - just create and register (in an `@NgModule`) another component. It will have a selector, which you can use in another component's html, like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
   <some-other-component></some-other-component>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Sorry, you can give more detail/link about `Create another component and place the html template you need inside home.ts there.`?

Comment: I have added an explanation in the answer

Comment: Sorry, being an angular noob, I think I'm still missing something. Can you give additional links/tutorials that explain your answer in more details? Thanks

Comment: This should be a good start for me right http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/09/angular-create-reusable-component-and.html

Comment: Well, yes, this can be a start, it explains how to create, reuse and connect components. There you go